# Javascript Google Charts change data

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a function to change the data in a Google Charts scatter chart but when I call the function the chart doesn't change. Heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005];
var sales = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  var data;
  var options;
  var chart;

  function drawChart() {
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'years');
  data.addColumn('number', 'sales');

  for(i = 0; i < years.length; i++)
    data.addRow([years[i], sales[i]]);

        options = {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    $(document).ready(function(){
         changeData();
    });

     function changeData()
     {
        data.addRow(10, 10);
        chart.draw(data, options); 
     }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the code.

The first one: you are calling on load `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` and also `changeData();` It seems that `changeData()` is started first because there is error reported:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addRow' of undefined
```

One option to fix it is to call `changeData();` at the end of `drawChart()` function.

The next one: call

```
data.addRow(10, 10);
```

has to be changed to something like:

```
data.addRow([2006, 10]);
```

because `addRow()` expects an array.

And min and max values have to be changed.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xisoz/1/).

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I can call this function automatically at some point after the initial setOnLoadCallback is called? I tried setting it as the body onload func but it didnt work.

Comment: One option is to use `setTimeout()` which will call `changeData()` after some timeout. 500 ms could be enough.

Comment: The other option is to rearrange your code and move most of it to body section. See updated [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xisoz/2/edit).